# How to create custom request in Facebook Open Graph?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

I am slightly confused about this whole open graph thing despite reading about it.

How would I go about customizing it if I just want to change "xxx has sent you a request" to simply "xxx has sent you a challenge request" or "xxx has challenged you in yyy", along with a custom message the user can type in?

I also can't seem to restrict the list to people who already have played the game before, the dialog just shows All, Game Players, and Friends to Invite. I want to only show Game Players (and even then how can I customise this text?).

I am using the Unity's SDK, FB.AppRequest, with just a hardcode message (which doesn't seen to appear anywhere) and title of the ingame dialog popup. Basically now I just want to complete a game, and then challenge friends to beat my score (with a custom user message in that request for friends to read).

edit: how do I know if a request came in and loaded the app? Do I simply delete all notifications for the app for simplicity?

Answer (score 0):

v5.1 of the SDK has Structured Requests which let you use Open Graph objects so you can do "xxx sent you a shoe"  or "xxx asked for a sock".  However, we don't have a "xxx has challenged you in yyy"

If you look at the `InteractiveConsole.cs` example, you can see that it uses `"[\"all\",\"app_users\",\"app_non_users\"]"` to specify the exact tabs to show.  You can change this in your own code to be just: `"[\"app_users\"]"` for showing only Game Players.  Currently this label isn't customizable, but you can create your own custom list with a customized label.  See "filters" in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ for more details.

You can see if a player came in with a request through FB.GetDeepLink().  That will fetch the raw url along with the url params such as the request id.  You can check for that to respond appropriately to requests.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would Open Graph allow me to do xxx sent you a challenge? i.e. replace shoe with challenge. which in fact does nothing but just opens up the app? I have not seen the updated InteractiveConsole.cs yet, but I hope it has an sample for using structured request!

Also, it seems like the filters only works in Canvas and not Android/iOS yet. If I am to customize it for Canvas, how would I go about doing that in Unity? It seems like the "customization" is basically me manually making a list of usernames instead of everyone  in the supposed default list by default.